# Magento 2.2.6 Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in vendor/magento/framework/App/Valitron.php on line 1293

Tags: magento2, url, notification

I use magento 2.2.6 i have this notice with valiton.php from 2 days, i don't understand why.
The message is :

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in /var/www/vhosts/bonbonrose.ch/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Valitron.php on line 1293

Here the part of code line 1293

```
 if ($this->validateSecureUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $secureKey = 'login';
        if (!empty($_POST[$secureKey]) && is_array($_POST[$secureKey])) {
            if ($this->executeSecureValidate($_POST[$secureKey])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Someone know how to fix ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an old code within Magento Framework package.
The following solution helped me:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/bonbonrose.ch/httpdocs
rm -rf vendor/magento/framework
composer install
```

In case if the file persists after performing the above mentioned commands then I would recommend one of the options below:

1) update Magento to a newer release

2) replace the line:

```
if ($this->validateSecureUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
```

with

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && $this->validateSecureUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
```